# User input filtering - do I need to filter HTML?

Tags: php, security, user-input, validation

*Note: I take care of SQL injection and output escaping elsewhere - this question is about input filtering only, thanks.*

I'm in the middle of refactoring my user input filtering functions. Before passing the GET/POST parameter to a type-specific filter with [filter_var()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) I do the following:

- check the parameter encoding with [mb_detect_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)
- convert to UTF-8 with [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) (with //IGNORE) if it's not ASCII or UTF-8
- clean white-spaces with [a function found on GnuCitizen.org](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/snippets-of-defense-ptiv/)
- pass the result thru [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) - no tags allowed at all, Markdown only

Now the question: does it still make sense to pass the parameter to a filter like [htmLawed](http://code.google.com/p/htmlawed/) or [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), or can I think of the input as safe? It seems to me that these two differ mostly on the granularity of allowed HTML elements and attributes (which I'm not interested into, as I remove everything), but htmLawed docs have a section about '[dangerous characters](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/htmLawed_README.htm#s3.1)' that suggests there might be a reason to use it. In this case, what would be a sane configuration for it?

Comment: Dangerous character could be UTF-8 control characters.

Comment: Any suggestion about how to get rid of them?

Comment: I don't really get your note, SQL Injection is all about preventing nasty user input in a sql query.  In fact the majority of vulnerabilities are becuase of nasty INPUT,  not output.   These are called "Taint and Sink" vulnerabilities.

Comment: I'm using prepared statements (AKA parametrized queries) for everything that goes near a database and AFAIK this is as bulletproof as it comes. I was specifically asking myself what *else* might be out there to be careful about - and Jacco's comment is a great example of such a situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different approaches to XSS that are secure.  The only why to know if your approach holds water is to test though exploitation. I recommend using a [Free XSS vulnerability Scanner](https://sitewat.ch/About/XSS)*,  or the open source [wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/).

To be honest I'll never use strip_tags() becuase you don't always need html tags to execute javascript! I like `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` .

For instance this is vulnerable to xss:

```
print('<A HREF="http://www.xssed.com/'.strip_tags($_REQUEST[xss]).'">link</a>');
```

You don't need <>  to execute javascript in this case because you can use 
onmouseover,  here is an example attack:

```
$_REQUEST[xss]='" onMouseOver="alert(/xss/)"';
```

The ENT_QUOTES will take care of the double quotes which will patch this XSS vulnerability.

*I am affiliated with this site/service.

Comment: Very good point! Thank you!  
I found a list of events at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#82180 and passed the array to a str_ireplace() - this should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you're doing is safe, at least from my point of view no html code should get through your filter

Comment: -1 Yeah, but javascript can still make it though these filters.