# What characters to strip from messages?

Tags: php, validation

I'm quite surprised I haven't been able to find out what characters I need to strip from a message in order to keep my application safe.

I've got a php app, and most of the inputs are numerical, but I'm adding the ability for users to attache messages, so I need to cleanse the message and strip any characters that could be a threat.

My initial reaction was if I did

```
$message=addslashes(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-,& $%\(\)#@!\'\"?.]/','',$_POST['message']));
```

I'd be safe, but I haven't been able to find anything which states what characters can be damaging, and what characters would be safe.

Comment: There are already a lot questions about input filtering. Just have a look at right side of this page. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305435/user-input-filtering-do-i-need-to-filter-html

Comment: Thanks Felix, but it seems none of those questions (that I looked at) really answered the question of 'what characters are a threat. At the same time, the HTML Purifier seems to be the way to go, and I hadn't heard of that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you don't have to strip any characters from your input, at least generally speaking.

Instead, **you must escape** your data :

- when sending it to your database

  - see [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://fr.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string), [`PDO::quote`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)
  - or Prepared statements : [MySQLi](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) ; [PDO](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- when sending it to the HTML output

  - see [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Still, if you allow users to input HTML, you should take a look at [HTMLPurifier][7], to make sure they are not able to inject any malicious HTML code into your web-pages :

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
> HTML filter library written in    PHP.
> HTML Purifier will not only remove all
> malicious code (better known as
> XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it
> will also make sure your documents are
> standards compliant

Comment: “[…] to make sure they are able to inject any malicious HTML code […]” – Don’t you mean the opposite?

Comment: @Gumbo : ouch ; of course I mean the opposite ;-) ;; I've edited my answer to correct than ;; thanks for your comment !

Comment: htmlspecialchars can be dangerous for UTF-8 coded character sets

Answer (score 1):

**[This is where HTML Purifier comes in handy.](http://htmlpurifier.org/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sanitizing your data just use Prepared Statements for database interaction. PDOs eliminate the need of hand santizing all of your input yourself.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: but aren't there other concerns besides just database interactions?